# Listview not load items after resume

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-10, uwp

I have an application with a listview with itemsource pdf images related to this example:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/PDF-viewer-showcase-sample-39ced1e8

My problem is once the application is suspended, and then is resumed, the list view does not load more items.
That is, once resumed, you see only the items in the listview already loaded earlier (before the suspended), but no longer loads the other elements.
How do I fix it, without initializing the itemsource again?

```
 pdfDocument = await Windows.Data.Pdf.PdfDocument.LoadFromFileAsync(pdfFile);
 PdfDocViewModel pdfDataSourceZoomedInView = new PdfDocViewModel(pdfDocument, pageSize, SurfaceType.VirtualSurfaceImageSource);
 this.listview.ItemsSource = this.pdfDataSourceZoomedInView;


<DataTemplate x:Name="zoomedInViewItemTemplate" x:DataType="model:PdfPageViewModel">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" >
                    <Image Source="{x:Bind ImageSourceVsisBackground ,Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="{x:Bind Height, Mode=OneWay}" Width="{x:Bind Width ,Mode=OneWay}"></Image>
                    <Image Source="{x:Bind ImageSourceVsisForeground ,Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="{x:Bind Height, Mode=OneWay}" Width="{x:Bind Width ,Mode=OneWay}"></Image>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
```

this is the PdfDocViwModel class:

```
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved

//
// PdfDocViewModel.cpp
// Definition of the PdfDocViewModel class
//

#include "pch.h"
#include "PdfDocViewModel.h"
#include "ImageSourceVSIS.h"
#include "PdfViewContext.h"
#include "PdfPageViewModel.h"

using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Data;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop;
using namespace Platform;

namespace PdfViewModel
{
    PdfDocViewModel::PdfDocViewModel(_In_ Windows::Data::Pdf::PdfDocument^ pdfDoc, _In_ Windows::Foundation::Size pageSize, _In_ PdfViewModel::SurfaceType surfaceType)
        : pdfDocument(pdfDoc)
    {
        pdfViewContext = ref new PdfViewContext(pageSize, pdfDocument->GetPage(0)->Size, surfaceType);
        storage = ref new Collections::Vector<Object^>();
        storage->VectorChanged += ref new Windows::Foundation::Collections::VectorChangedEventHandler<Object^>(this, &PdfDocViewModel::StorageVectorChanged);
        isVectorChangedObserved = false;

        for (unsigned int pg = 0; pg < pdfDocument->PageCount; ++pg)
        {
            Append(CreateEmptyItem(pg));
        }
    }

#pragma region IBindableObservableVector

    Windows::Foundation::EventRegistrationToken PdfDocViewModel::VectorChanged::add(_In_ BindableVectorChangedEventHandler^ e)
    {
        isVectorChangedObserved = true;
        return privateVectorChanged += e;
    }

    void PdfDocViewModel::VectorChanged::remove(_In_ Windows::Foundation::EventRegistrationToken t)
    {
        privateVectorChanged -= t;
    }

    void PdfDocViewModel::VectorChanged::raise(_In_ IBindableObservableVector^ vector, _In_ Object^ e)
    {
        if (isVectorChangedObserved)
        {
            privateVectorChanged(vector, e);
        }
    }

#pragma endregion

#pragma region IBindableIterator

    IBindableIterator^ PdfDocViewModel::First()
    {
        return dynamic_cast<IBindableIterator^>(storage->First());
    }

#pragma endregion

#pragma region IBindableVector

    void PdfDocViewModel::Append(_In_ Object^ value)
    {
        storage->Append(value);
    }

    void PdfDocViewModel::Clear()
    {
        storage->Clear();
    }

    Object^ PdfDocViewModel::GetAt(_In_ unsigned int index)
    {
        Object^ item = storage->GetAt(index);
        if (item == nullptr)
        {
            item = CreateEmptyItem(index);
            SetAt(index, item);
        }
        RealizeItemIfNotAvailable(index, item);
        return item;
    }

    IBindableVectorView^ PdfDocViewModel::GetView()
    {
        return safe_cast<IBindableVectorView^>(storage->GetView());
    }

    bool PdfDocViewModel::IndexOf(_In_ Object^ value, _In_ unsigned int* index)
    {
        return storage->IndexOf(value, index);
    }

    void PdfDocViewModel::InsertAt(_In_ unsigned int index, _In_ Object^ value)
    {
        storage->InsertAt(index, value);
    }

    void PdfDocViewModel::RemoveAt(_In_ unsigned int index)
    {
        storage->RemoveAt(index);
    }

    void PdfDocViewModel::RemoveAtEnd()
    {
        storage->RemoveAtEnd();
    }

    void PdfDocViewModel::SetAt(_In_ unsigned int index, _In_ Object^ value)
    {
        storage->SetAt(index, value);
    }

    unsigned int PdfDocViewModel::Size::get()
    {
        return storage->Size;
    }

#pragma endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// This function is used to create empty PdfPageViewModel items
    /// </summary>
    Object^ PdfDocViewModel::CreateEmptyItem(_In_ unsigned int index)
    {
        auto obj = ref new PdfPageViewModel(pdfDocument, index);
        obj->SetViewContext(pdfViewContext);
        return obj;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This function should be used to realize the item (do some initialization tasks if required).
    /// </summary>
    void PdfDocViewModel::RealizeItemIfNotAvailable(_In_ unsigned int /*index*/, _In_ Object^ /*item*/)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Call this method when the app suspends to hint to the driver that the app is entering an idle state
    /// and that its memory can be used temporarily for other apps.
    /// </summary>
    void PdfDocViewModel::Trim()
    {
        pdfViewContext->Renderer->Trim();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Function to update page based on current zoomFactor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="currentZoomFactor">Current zoom factor of scroll viewer</param>
    void PdfDocViewModel::UpdatePages(_In_ float currentZoomFactor)
    {
        if (pdfViewContext->ZoomFactor != currentZoomFactor)
        {
            pdfViewContext->ZoomFactor = currentZoomFactor;
            if (pdfViewContext->SurfaceType == SurfaceType::VirtualSurfaceImageSource)
            {
                for (unsigned int index = 0, len = Size; index < len; index++)
                {
                    auto pageData = dynamic_cast<PdfPageViewModel^>(storage->GetAt(index));
                    if ((pageData != nullptr) && !pageData->IsUnloaded())
                    {
                        pageData->UpdateSurface();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

#pragma region State

    /// <summary>
    /// Event handler for store vector changed
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">IVectorChangedEventArgs</param>
    void PdfDocViewModel::StorageVectorChanged(_In_ Windows::Foundation::Collections::IObservableVector<Object^>^ /*sender*/, _In_ Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVectorChangedEventArgs^ e)
    {
        if (isVectorChangedObserved)
        {
            VectorChanged(this, e);
        }
    }
#pragma endregion
}
```

Comment: You will need to add a code snippet to show what you are doing

Comment: IT keeps erroring out when I post an answer, but that because when you set the list source, your list doesn't inherit observable. Put this.listview.Items.Refresh(); When you update your list

Comment: this method is not for uwp app

Comment: You set a PdfDocViewModel type data as the ItemsSource  using `PdfDocViewModel pdfDataSourceZoomedInView = new PdfDocViewModel(pdfDocument, pageSize, SurfaceType.VirtualSurfaceImageSource);` Can you please post the code in `PdfDocViewMode`?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT I edited the question.